# Over ride magento template file

Tags: cart, template

I want to over ride checkout/cart/item/default.phtml file in my extension in order to add certain details on the cart page below product name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out solution of the above question

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
 <reference name="checkout.cart">
  <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>extname/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>extname/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>extname/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

 </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
```

Just add the above code  into the frontend xml of your extension.